# How to use custom search to get data in html file?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-search-provider

How can we use custom search to find website links using java-script, I mean depend on links  titles, search result will be appeared on page.

Here is the code:

```
<tr><td class="lpage"><a href="http://www.google.com/" title="Google">Google</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lpage"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" title="Yahoo">Yahoo</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lpage"><a href="http://www.bing.com/" title="Bing">Bing</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lpage"><a href="http://www.1.com/" title="1">1</a></td></tr>
//and more links
```

For exp: If someone search Yahoo in custom search, then cause title of Yahoo is exist, yahoo link with it's title name will be appeared in search result.
Actually I'm gonna use this for sitemap.

Is it possible to use java-script for this custom search in html?

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML parser such as [*htmlparser*](https://npmjs.org/package/htmlparser) to extract all `href` elements

Comment: I downloaded node-htmlparser-master file, but there is no custom search template that I'll understand how i can use it.. Is it possible for you to give me a example... Include of that htmlparser file are just js file, actually i donnu how to use it...

Comment: @Amin the link that I posted contains code examples, just scroll down ;)